# Nodejs Sequelize instance timeout when connecting to mysql container

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, sequelize.js, apache2

I have a Node.js server running on an Ubuntu-20.04 Virtual Machine.
I'm using `docker compose` to setup a mysql container with a production database.

My `docker-compose.yml` file is like so,

```yaml
prod_db:
    image: mysql:latest
    restart: always
    environment: 
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PRODUCTION_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_PRODUCTION_DATABASE}
    ports:
      - ${MYSQL_PRODUCTION_PORT}:3306
```

Running `docker compose up` on it appears to work fine,

`lockers-prod_db-1  | 2022-08-08T19:18:03.005576Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.30'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.`

And `docker container list` yields the following,

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                                  NAMES
33289149af9f   mysql:latest   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   37 seconds ago   Up 35 seconds   33060/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3308->3306/tcp, :::3308->3306/tcp   lockers-prod_db-1
```

But yet when attempting to connect via the `Sequelize` with the following code,

```js
config = {
        id: 'production',
        port: process.env.NODE_PORT,
        sqlConfig: {
            port: parseInt(process.env.MYSQL_PRODUCTION_PORT),
            host: process.env.MYSQL_PRODUCTION_HOST,
            user: process.env.MYSQL_PRODUCTION_USER,
            password: process.env.MYSQL_PRODUCTION_PASSWORD,
            database: process.env.MYSQL_PRODUCTION_DATABASE,
            locationsCsvPath: process.env.LOCATIONS_CSV_ABSOLUTE_PATH,
            lockersCsvPath: process.env.LOCKERS_CSV_ABSOLUTE_PATH,
            contractsCsvPath: process.env.CONTRACTS_CSV_ABSOLUTE_PATH
        }


const sequelize = new Sequelize({
    dialect: 'mysql',
    host: config.sqlConfig.host,
    port: config.sqlConfig.port,
    password: config.sqlConfig.password,
    username: config.sqlConfig.user,
    database: config.sqlConfig.database,
    models: [Contract, Location, Locker],
    logging: false
});
```

I get the following error,

```
/home/freemaa7/lockers/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connection-manager.js:102
          throw new SequelizeErrors.ConnectionError(err);
                ^

ConnectionError [SequelizeConnectionError]: connect ETIMEDOUT
    at ConnectionManager.connect (/home/freemaa7/lockers/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connection-manager.js:102:17)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async ConnectionManager._connect (/home/freemaa7/lockers/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:220:24)
    at async /home/freemaa7/lockers/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:174:32
    at async ConnectionManager.getConnection (/home/freemaa7/lockers/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:197:7)
    at async /home/freemaa7/lockers/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:301:26
    at async MySQLQueryInterface.tableExists (/home/freemaa7/lockers/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-interface.js:102:17)
    at async Function.sync (/home/freemaa7/lockers/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:939:21)
    at async Sequelize.sync (/home/freemaa7/lockers/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:373:9) {
  parent: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
      at Connection._handleTimeoutError (/home/freemaa7/lockers/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:189:17)
      at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
      at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7) {
    errorno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
    code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
    syscall: 'connect',
    fatal: true
  },
  original: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
      at Connection._handleTimeoutError (/home/freemaa7/lockers/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:189:17)
      at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
      at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7) {
    errorno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
    code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
    syscall: 'connect',
    fatal: true
  }
}
```

I'm running this on a virtual machine, this works perfectly locally though. The main difference is that on the VM an apache2 instance is running. I'm starting to think it may be redirecting the TPC requests to the container to another address because it's setup as a reverse proxy. Could this be a possibility ?

Comment: In this setup, the database is in a container on a VM, and the application is outside a container but in the same VM?  What are the actual values you're passing for those environment variables?

Comment: Yes, the application is in the same VM but not in a container, the database is in a container on the VM. MYSQL_PRODUCTION_PORT has a value of 3308 which I believe is the port the database container is listening on. MYSQL_PRODUCTION_HOST has a value of 127.0.0.1, yes I have also tried localhost but to no avail.